# Magento 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p1 error after upgrade

Tags: issue

I'm new on the forum.
Recently I tried to upgrade my Magento from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p1. It didn't work.

I normally do both code and bd backups before and after any major change or module installation.

Now I want to reverse my Magento to the previous stage using one of my backups but for some reason, I can't do it.

I can't disable the maintenance mode to clear cache and so on.
I'mconcedering putting a new Magento 2.4.3-p1 from scratch but I need some data from this broken one. Especially product data.

Can somebody help, please? I have 10s of backups in my /var/backups directory. How can I use them to make my Magento work again?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

I’m still fighting and I can't fix the issue. I'm guessing that the Magento upgrade is causing the issue. In the past, I mean, before I tried to upgrade Magneto, restoring backups on the same Magento version, was easy with no complications but after I tried to upgrade it doesn't work.

It is really annoying because I have 10s of backups and I restored backups 10s of times.
I would like to give more tetails what I did.
I had Magento 2.4.2 and tried to upgrade to 2.4.3-1
It didn't work so I tried to restore my backup runing the following commands:

`bin/magento setup:rollback --code-file="code_file_name_code.tgz"`

`bin/magento setup:rollback --db-file="db_file_name_db.sql"`

**Checked ownership & permissions with these commands:**

Using superuser:

`sudo chown -R magento:www-data /var/www/html/`

‘Magento’ user:

`find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento`

**Removed the following runing the below command:**

`rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*`
`rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* generated/*`

**Finally restarted my Redis:**
Using superuser:

`sudo systemctl status redis-server`

Flushed Redis with the below command:

`REDISCLI_AUTH='my_password' redis-cli FLUSHALL`

In the past, I never had to touch Redis.
I never set up Varnish so didn't flush it.

Can anyone help and give me a tip on how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Remove the cache, like "rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* generated/*".

Comment: If still doesn't work, then restart your varnish and redis.

Comment: Hello Sohel, thank you for taking the time and responding to me. I tried both but it didn't help. Have you got any more sugesstions? Pls

Comment: Hello Pawel, Once again check the your command like php bin/magento cache:flush 

May be PHP word missing in your command.

Answer (score -1):

Once again check the your command like

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

PHP word missing in your command.